# ¿Cómo sumar una nueva cantidad a un registro de la BD y mandar una notificación?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema y no se por donde empezar espero me puedan asesorar: En mi base de datos, tengo una tabla con el campo vehículo y odómetro que son los kilómetros recorridos de ese y otros vehículos, tengo un formulario donde voy insertando los kilómetros que van recorriendo mis vehículos pero quiero que cada vez que registre al mismo vehículo un nuevo kilometraje se le sume al anterior automáticamente y cuando llegue a un tope, que serán 10000, me mande una notificación de que llegó a su límite.

Este es mi formulario muy sencillo:

```
    <form class="container" id="frmcarga" method="POST">
      <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="">Vehículo</label>
           <select  name="vehiculo" id="vehiculo" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
            <?php
               $query="SELECT  * FROM vehiculo";
                $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

                echo '<option value="'.$row['vehiculo'].'">'.$row['vehiculo'].'</option>';
              }
            ?>
          </select> 
         </div> 


        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="">Odómetro</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">KM</span>
    </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control numerico" name="kilometro" id="kilometro">
    </div> 
     </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

aquí hago la consulta para insertar a la base de datos:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$vehiculo=$_POST['vehiculo'];
$kilometro=$_POST['kilometro'];

$insert="INSERT INTO carga_combustible(vehiculo , odometro) VALUES ('$vehiculo', '$kilometro')";

mysqli_query($con,$insert) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Así mando mis datos por Ajax:

```
function validaForm19(){
   // Campos de texto
    if($("#vehiculo").val() == ""){
        //alert("El campo Nombre no puede estar vacío.");
        $("#ms1").delay(100).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#vehiculo").focus();// Esta función coloca el foco de escritura del usuario en el campo Nombre directamente.
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#ms1").fadeOut();      
    }

if($("#kilometro").val() == ""){

        $("#ms8").delay(100).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#kilometro").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#ms8").fadeOut();      
    }


     return true; 
}


$(document).ready( function() { 
 $("#btnguardar").click( function() {
  if(validaForm19()){ 
  $.post("scripts/reg_cargacombustible.php",$("#frmcarga").serialize(),function(res){

                if(res == 1){
                     //alert("Fallo al agregar");
                  Swal.fire({
                   type: 'error',
                   title: 'Oops...',
                   text: 'Fallo al agregar',                  
                   });
                } else {
                    //alert("Vehículo agregado con éxito!!");
                    Swal.fire({
                     position:'center',
                     type: 'success',
                     title: 'Recarga de combustible agregada con éxito!!',
                     showConfirmButton: false,
                     timer: 1500
                     });
                    document.getElementById("frmcarga").reset();//codigo para limpiar datos del form
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

aquí solo forme el cuerpo de la notificación:

```
Push.create("ALERTA DE MANTENIMIENTO NIVEL MEDIO",{
            body:"Usted tiene un mantenimiento de vehículo pendiente!!!",
            icon:"img/alerta_media.png",
            //timeout:4000,
            onClick: function(){
                window.location="reg_mantenimiento.php";
                this.close();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que traigas el valor del kilometraje desde la base de datos `$row['kilometro']`, le sumas con `javascript` el kilometraje ingresado en `id="kilometro"` y envías por `post` el resultado.

Comment: el detalle es que cada vez que hago un insert es un nuevo registro con diferente id pero para el mismo vehículo si hago esto $row['kilometro'] me va a tomar un solo registro y no todos y quiero que tome todos los del mismo vehículo para ir sumandolos

Comment: Otra opción es que sumes los kilómetros acumulados por X vehículo... algo parecido a esto: `SELECT SUM(odometro) AS totalKilometros FROM carga_combustible WHERE vehiculo = 'elVehiculoQueSea';`. Digo... solo son opciones que se me ocurren!

Comment: si funciono esa consulta ahora el detalle es que la haga automáticamente cada vez que se inserta un nuevo kilometraje quizás si es mejor hacerlo con javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como te indico en mi comentario, con la siguiente sentencia puedes sumar los valores:

```
SELECT SUM(odometro) AS totalKilometros FROM carga_combustible WHERE vehiculo = 'elVehiculoQueSea';
```

El resultado lo pones en un `input` con `id="totalKilometros"` puede ser con atributo `hidden`

Y de acuerdo a tu comentario, para mostrar la alerta podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
$(#totalKilometros).load(function(){
  var totalKilometros = $(this).val();
  if(totalKilometros >= 10000)
    alert("Este vehículo necesita mantenimiento");
});
```

Comment: no me manda la alerta como que no toma el valor que se inserto en el input y si lo recupero bien de mi consulta por que aparece la suma correcta

Comment: la funcion.change para detectar cambios solo funciona si yo escribo manualmente dentro del input y no cuando aumenta la suma previamente utilizada

Comment: Es correcto. Pero si traes la suma previamente de la base de datos y luego le incrementas el valor actual, obtienes un cambio de datos en ese `input`. Como te decía, solo son ejemplos que te pongo ya que estoy fuera de contexto con tu proyecto completo. Puedes usar `.load()` o el método que más se acomode a tu necesidad.

Comment: De hecho, para no enredarte, si deseas, elimino la respuesta. O en su defecto eliminas tu pregunta y creas una nueva con mayor precisión para que captures la atención de un usuario más experimentado. Lo dejo a tu criterio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes traer la suma ya hecha.
con algo así:

```
SELECT SUM (kilometro) as KilometrosTotales FROM vehiculo WHERE 'idVehiculo= id del vehiculo'
```

de tal forma que KilometrosTotales, será la suma de los kilometros que vas introduciendo en los registros de la BD, luego ya comparas con 10000 y mandas un Alert().

Comment: si ya realice ese paso pero como le haría para cada vez que se inserte un nuevo kilometraje se realice esa consulta para que vaya sumando y para realizar la comparación se hace con sentencias sql? u obtengo el valor total y luego con javascripit hago la comparacion y mando el alert